# Use a laptop to find out which port it on a HP switch port it is connected to

Tags: networking, hp

I think most people ask this question the other way around - having access to the switch and querying a MAC address.

I my test laptop and was wondering if there is a software (maybe by HP) that would tell me which switch and port the laptop is currently plugged into? Please assume that I do not have access to the switch management.
If this is indeed information that the switch would give out (security implications) - I could write my own application, if someone could point out which protocol would be used.

What I would need for my job is:
I would go to a random room, plug my laptop into an ethernet port on the wall and it will tell me which switch and port I am connected to.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the switch and the configuration of that switch.

There are several protocols that might be running (CDP on cisco switches, NDP on nortel, LLDP, ...) which can tell you what switch and port you're at.

To gather those information you just have to listen to the network traffic.

Using tcpdump to get CDP packets:

```
tcpdump -nn -v -i eth0 -s 1500 -c 1 'ether[20:2] == 0x2000'
```

and for lldp:

```
tcpdump -nn -v -i eth0 -s 1500 -c 1 'ether[12:2] == 0x88cc'
```

I would check what brands of switches are present and then find out what discovery protocols they might use and then just sniff for the candidates (it might take a few minutes until you receive a packet).

[LLDP Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Layer_Discovery_Protocol)
[CDP Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_Discovery_Protocol)
[NDP Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nortel_Discovery_Protocol)

Comment: I guess I did not translate that well into wireshark - but this worked for LLDP  (As it looks like HP does not use CDP anymore). (eth.dst == 01:80:c2:00:00:0e)